# Modifying the Collation Type across an Entire Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to modify the collation type across an entire table, and currently have the following query to modify a column at a time

```
ALTER TABLE <table>
    ALTER COLUMN <column>
VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN NOT NULL
```

Attempting to run the query below across the whole table though, isn't working

```
ALTER TABLE <table>
VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN NOT NULL
```

What am I missing, that would cause this to change the collation type for the entire table vs a column at a time?

Comment: Collation can be set at the column or database level. AFAIK there is no such thing as table level collation.

Comment: What would the correct statement to establish collation at the DB level retroactively? Other posts talk about how to set the default going forward for a DB, but nothing I've come across has allowed for a retroactive change to an existing DB.

Comment: You would have to change the collation of each column for tables that already exist. I don't know of a shortcut to this. But you can use sys.tables and sys.columns to help you build some dynamic sql to make this pretty painless.